# Key-Value pair functionality inside a C# array

Tags: c#, syntax, key-value, dynamic-arrays, jagged-arrays

I am trying to get a 'multidimensional' jagged array working for my major data-transform work. I want the innermost array to have the key-value pair behavior of an object, But I don't know what syntax to use:

```
object[][][] courseData = new object[][][] 
  {
      new object[][]//chapter 1
      {
        new object[]
        {

          {id = 1, question = "question", answer = "answer"},
          //this one?
          (id = 2, question = "question", answer = "answer"),
          //or this one?
        }
      }
   }
```

Much of this syntax is new to me, so please let me know what other errors I have made.

If key-value pairs in arrays are impossible, I will have to use unnamed index references, right? that would use () on build and [0] as reference, yes? Can this array even hold mixed data types outside the object?

ps: an example of a function that will be doing work on this data:

```
function mapOrder (array, order, key) {

  array.sort( function (a, b) {
    var A = a[key], B = b[key];

    if (order.indexOf(A) > order.indexOf(B)) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }

  });

  return array;
};


reordered_array_a = mapOrder(courseData[0][0], orderTemplateSimple[0], id);
```

Where orderTemplateSample[index] is an array of numbers used to transform the order of the 'extracted' array from courseData.

I want to have the id key reference there, but if I have to replace it with a number that would theoretically work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from the *inmost* type, that is

```
  {id = 1, question = "question", answer = "answer"},
```

it *can't* be a key value *pair* since it has *three* properties: `id, question, answer`.
However, you can turn it into *named tuple*

```
  (int id, string question, string answer)
```

The declaration will be

```
  (int id, string question, string answer)[][][] courseData = 
     new (int, string, string)[][][]
  {
      new (int, string, string)[][]//chapter 1
      {
        new (int, string, string)[]
        {
           // Long form
          (id : 1, question : "question", answer : "answer"),
    
           // Short form: we can skip id, question, answer names 
          (2, "question", "answer"),
        }
      }
   };
```

Now you have an *array* (array of array of array to be exact):

```
   int course = 1;
   int chapter = 1;
   int question = 2;

   // - 1 since arrays are zero based
   string mySecondAnswer = courseData[course - 1][chapter - 1][question - 1].answer;
```

Comment: "OOoooh... AAAaaahh" quick questions though, what would adding a property after the fact look like? Do all my properties need to be declared on initialization?

Comment: @BetterLife exe: technically, you can use `ExpandoObject` (`System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject`) and add properties dynamically, but I doubt if you really need it